# Telling HashSet how to sort the data

Tags: java, hashset

I'm trying to create a HashSet (or any collection type - but I think HashSet will suit me best) that will remain in order no matter what is inserted. It's for a contact manager project I am working on.
I've been experimenting, with the example below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestDriver{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FullName person1 = new FullName("Stephen", "Harper");
        FullName person2 = new FullName("Jason", "Kenney");
        FullName person3 = new FullName("Peter", "MacKay");
        FullName person4 = new FullName("Rona", "Ambrose");
        FullName person5 = new FullName("Rona", "Aabrose");


        HashSet<FullName> names = new HashSet<FullName>();

        names.add(person3);
        names.add(person1);
        names.add(person4);
        names.add(person2);

        System.out.println(names);      
   } 
}
```

I expected the output to put the names in alphabetical order - at least according to either their first or last name. However, I can't even discern the method HashSet used to come up with this ordering;

```
[Jason Kenney, Rona Ambrose, Stephen Harper, Peter MacKay]
```

My question is, how do I tell my program how to sort the names based on my specifications?

Comment: Sorting a` HashSet` is a contradiction in terms. What you are looking for is any implementation of `SortedSet`, such as `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HashSet does not provide any meaningful order to the entries. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) says:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

To get a sensible ordering, you need to use a different Set implementation such as [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) or [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html). These implementations of the [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface let you provide a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that specifies how to order the entries; something like:

```
public class SortByLastName implements Comparator<FullName>{
    public int compare(FullName n1, FullName n2) {
        return n1.getLastName().compareTo(n2.getLastName());
    }
}

TreeSet<FullName> names = new TreeSet<FullName>(new SortByLastName());
```

You could instead make the FullName class implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, but this might be unhelpful if you wanted to sometimes sort by last name, sometimes by first name, or other criteria.

Answer (score 12):

use `Treeset` for natural ordering.

```
HashSet--- not ordered/sorted
LinkedhashSet--- maintains insertion order
TreeSet--- sorts in natural order
```

for your case use TreeSet instead.

Answer (score 9):

`HashSet` doesn't preserve order, Go for `TreeSet` and implement your own `Comparator` to instruct `TreeSet` how to compare

```
new TreeSet<FullName>(new Comparator<FullName>(){
        public int compare(Fullname one, FullName two{/*logic*/}
});
```

---

**See**

- [API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you need [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to achieve alphabetical order or [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to preserve insertion order.

Note that your `FullName` must implement `Comparable<FullName>` in order to be used in `TreeSet` (or you have to provide external Comparator`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 System.out.println(names.toList.sorted)
```

Comment: No, I'm running scala.