# Sort the hashset based on date

Tags: java

How can i sort the data  inside a hashset based on date

I have a program in which i will get the data from mongodb in this format `2015-01-17` and later i will convert it to `MMM dd yyyy` format and now how can i sort the data here ??

This is my program

```
public class MyObject {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sym = "BAC";
        Set<String> set = myDAO.getInstance().getMeAllExpirationDates(sym);
        for (String String : set) {

            System.out.println(String);
        }
    }

    public Set<String> getMeAllExpirationDates(String sym) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("symbol", sym);
        Security sec = null;
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            sec = (Security) cursor.next();
            Date date = sdf1.parse(sec.getTkExpirationDate());
            String result = sdf2.format(date);
            set.add(result);
        }
        return set;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Store it converted to Date type (using sdf1 in your example, and not string) 2. sort 3. output, formatting the Date type to the desired format. Though HashSet is not the good for this as it is not an ordered structure...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Telling HashSet how to sort the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129390/telling-hashset-how-to-sort-the-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the implmentation [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to keep the order of insertion

replace

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

with

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

Better yet, use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and sort the entries while adding them right away.

Answer (score 3):

`HashSet` is an unordered collection - its elements are not stored in any particular order. You can regard `HashSet` as a bag that contains items - the items are all in the bag, but not in any particular order.

If you want a `Set` that contains elements in a specific order, use an implementation of `SortedSet`, for example `TreeSet`, instead of `HashSet`.

`TreeSet` by default stores its elements in "natural order", if you want a different order you can use the `TreeSet` constructor that takes a `Comparator`; supply your own `Comparator` that defines the order you want the elements to be sorted in.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest was is to use a `Comparator`.  You will need to implement the `Comparable` interface in your objects to tell them how dates relate to each other. See [Telling HashSet how to sort the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129390/telling-hashset-how-to-sort-the-data) for a concrete answer to your question.