# How to sort Hashset<> by field?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I have a `Set<MultiAdminComponent> rootItems = new HashSet<>();`HashSet.
In this I have all my [Screen.](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgfuZho0E8Gi5d1CbOrH?p=preview)

In my `HashSet` I am going to have all my rows. I want to sort the `MultiAdminComponent` based on `rowId`.

**This is MultiAdminComponent**

```
 public class MultiAdminComponent {

        private String componentName;
        private String componentIdentification;
        private String componentType;
        private String componentState;
        private String componentUrl;
        private String componentId;
        private String rowId;
        private List<MultiAdminComponent> items;
        private int componentStateId;
        private int ctastatus;
        private String actionId;
        private String actionToPerform;
        private int orderNumber;
        private int ctarevision;
```

How can I sort based on RowId in `MultiAdminComponent` bean

Comment: what version of Java are you using ?

Comment: I am using Java 1.8 Version

Comment: Try to look into streams and filters, you will need to probably create a comparator as well, gonna d a simple example for you in a minute.

Comment: MultiAdminComponent has list of MultiAdminComponent items field ? it is strange, please check the model.

Comment: `List<MultiAdminComponent>` items  is  for, I have return a recursive method to find the parents and childs

Comment: How does your `rowID` look like? what format it is ? it is just a number? because it a string

Comment: yes it is going to be parent `1` child of 1 is `1.1` and `1.2` for `1.1` child is `1.1.1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telling HashSet how to sort the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129390/telling-hashset-how-to-sort-the-data)

Comment: rootItems containing all my rows

Comment: Not at it's a duplicate and this problem is entairly differnct.. Please check once

Comment: it actually is, there are plenty questions how to sort a collection, with a little of investigation you would find an answer. It is a very common question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are on Java 8, you can leverage `Stream API` and `Comparator.comparing()` for this:

```
List<MultiAdminComponent> sortedList = rootItems.stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MultiAdminComponent::getRowId))
   .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect to whatever you want
```

Keep in mind that `HashSet` does not maintain order so you should keep the sorted result in some other data structure.

And remember that this is not going to sort your `Set` this is going to return a `List` of naturally sorted `MultiAdminComponent`s and you need to capture the result of this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Just to let you know, there are few more Sets.

- `HashSet` is not ordered/sorted
- `LinkedHashSet` sorted by the order that it's been inserted
- `TreeSet` sorted in natural order

I know the question been answered, but truly I can't see a point of using a HashSet which is not ordered and then try to order it when you can just use a TreeSet?

Answer (score 1):

Before Java 1.8 version, which can help you

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiAdminComponent m1 = new MultiAdminComponent("1");
        MultiAdminComponent m2 = new MultiAdminComponent("2");
        MultiAdminComponent m3 = new MultiAdminComponent("3");
        Set<MultiAdminComponent> set = new HashSet<MultiAdminComponent>();
        set.add(m1);
        set.add(m3);
        set.add(m2);
        List<MultiAdminComponent> list = new ArrayList<MultiAdminComponent>(set);
        for (MultiAdminComponent m : list) {
            System.out.println("before" + m.getRowId());
        }
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MultiAdminComponent>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MultiAdminComponent m1, MultiAdminComponent m2) {
                return m1.getRowId().compareTo(m2.getRowId());
            }
        });
        for (MultiAdminComponent m : list) {
            System.out.println("after" + m.getRowId());
        }
    }
}

class MultiAdminComponent {
    private String rowId;

    public MultiAdminComponent(String rowId) {
        super();
        this.rowId = rowId;
    }

    public String getRowId() {
        return rowId;
    }

    public void setRowId(String rowId) {
        this.rowId = rowId;
    }

}
```